# Rewriting HTTP url to HTTPS using regular expression and javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm in a situation where I need to rewrite an url in javascript and switch it from http protocol to https.

I can match https urls with:

```
if(url.match('^http://')){
```

but how do I form the https url using regular expressions and javascript?

```
url =  "https://" + ?;
```

Comment: and if the user has javascript disabled?

Comment: our site has a disclaimer that already states it won't work in that case. Numerous things would be broken is javascript was disabled.

Comment: Security should not rely on the browser’s JavaScript support.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

Replace directly with a regex :

```
url = url.replace(/^http:\/\//i, 'https://');
```

Comment: Can someone please make it in usable form in java code? I tried copying it into my jsp, but it failed..

Comment: @AnandVaidya Try this : `url.replaceFirst("(?i)^http://", "https://");`

Answer (score 14):

Cannot it be done by simply replacing the **http** string?

```
if(url.match('^http://')){
     url = url.replace("http://","https://")
}
```

Comment: the first parameter of replace can be a regexp

Comment: watch out: double-back-slashes (//) can be confused to be a comment (e.g. by script bundlers, that clean up comments). 
Safer to write: ('http:/' + '/')

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your case, you might prefer to slice:

```
processed_url = "http" + initial_url.slice(5);
```

Example of http to https:

```
var initial_url;
var processed_url;

initial_url = "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5491196/rewriting-http-url-to-https-using-regular-expression-and-javascript";

processed_url = "https" + initial_url.slice(6);

console.log(processed_url)
```

Example of https to http:

```
var initial_url;
var processed_url;

initial_url = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5491196/rewriting-http-url-to-https-using-regular-expression-and-javascript";

processed_url = "http" + initial_url.slice(5);

console.log(processed_url)
```