# Editing start of a[href] http:// - https:// jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension, href

I am creating a Chrome extension which detects if the urls from Google search results are `http://` and if so make it `https://`.

I have done this so far.

```
$('a[href^="http://"]').attr('href', 'https://' + "a[href]");
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: Definitely a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5491196/rewriting-http-url-to-https-using-regular-expression-and-javascript - Use `url = url.replace(/^http:\/\//i, 'https://');`

Comment: @JeremyThille OP here appears to be looking for a jQuery solution though. In that respect it would not be a duplicate

Comment: Yeah, granted it's not an EXACT duplicate, but the solution is there (replace http with https)... I mean, a bit of research and you get what you want. No need for a new SO question. Anyway, that's my opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to replace the occurrence of `http://` with `https://`

```
$('a[href^="http://"]').attr('href', function(i,oldhref){
   oldhref.replace("http://","https://")
});
```

or

you can also use `.each()` to iterate over them:

```
$('a[href^="http://"]').each(function(){
   $(this).attr('href', $(this).attr('href').replace("http://","https://"))
});
```

Comment: you don't need to use `.each()`

Comment: What's the point of prepending `https://` to then replace the original `http://` with nothing?

Answer (score 1):

```
$('a[href^="http://"]').each(function(){
    var self = $(this);
    self.attr("href", self.attr("href").replace("http", "https"));
});
```

Should do it.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass `attr()` a function in which you can place logic to amend the current value of that attribute. Try this:

```
$('a[href^="http://"]').attr('href', function(i, v) {
    return v.replace(/^http:\/\//i, 'https://');
});
```